# Arguments for overridden docker entrypoint

Tags: docker

The Entrypoint of a docker image can be modified while running the image using --entrypoint in docker run command. I want to start a script in my image with some arguments at startup. I can get docker to run the script at startup as

```
    docker run -it --rm  --entrypoint /my/script/path.sh my-docker-image
```

How do I pass arguments to my script?

Note that I cannot modify the original dockerfile with which this image was created. Neither do I want to create another docker image with this image as its base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your Docker image has an `ENTRYPOINT`, either via a Dockerfile or provided on the command line with `--entrypoint`, any arguments on the `docker run` command line after the image name are passed to the entrypoint script.

So for example, if I have a script like this in `myscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Here are my arguments: $@"
```

And I run an image like this:

```
$ chmod 755 myscript.sh
$ docker run -it --rm -v $PWD/myscript.sh:/myscript.sh \
  --entrypoint /myscript.sh alpine one two three
```

I will see the output:

```
Here are my arguments: one two three
```

...and the container will exit, because the entrypoint script didn't arrange to do anything else.  You could replace `alpine` here (which is a minimal docker image) with any other Docker image that has `/bin/sh` (so, most of them).  For example:

```
$ docker run -it --rm -v $PWD/myscript.sh:/myscript.sh \
  --entrypoint /myscript.sh centos one two three
Here are my arguments: one two three
```

Note that I'm using the `-v` argument in this example to mount a script on my host into the container, since I didn't want to create a new image for the purposes of this example.  You could obviously bake a similar script into your image instead.

For details, read the [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint) docs.